# Calculating alarm time for alarm clock

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarmmanager

I am trying to make an alarm clock app and am having difficulty setting the time for the alarm to go off. My app has the user select which days they would like the alarm to go off, similar to the android alarm clock, with a boolean array of seven to represent this.

My idea was to set the clock for the closest day i.e if today is Monday and the alarm is set for Wednesday and Friday, the alarm will go off on Wednesday and then reset itself for Friday.

I was wondering if the calendar could return a week, I think this would make things easier.

Answer (score 3):

## Avoid old date-time classes

Avoid using the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. Instead use the java.time classes.

## `DayOfWeek` enum & `EnumMap`

The [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) has seven objects predefined for each of the seven days of the week, Monday-Sunday.

`EnumSet` and [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) are very fast and low-memory implementations of `Set` and `Map` for handling a collection of enum values. In your case you could define an `EnumMap` with all seven days, each mapping to a `LocalTime` for when alarm should fire (or null for no alarm that day).

```
EnumMap< DayOfWeek , LocalTime > dowToTimeMap = new EnumMap< DayOfWeek , LocalTime >( DayOfWeek.class );

dowToTimeMap.put( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , LocalTime.of( 6 , 0 ) );  // 6 AM.
dowToTimeMap.put( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , LocalTime.of( 6 , 0 ) );
…
dowToTimeMap.put( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ); // Sleep in until 8 AM on Saturday.
dowToTimeMap.put( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY , LocalTime.of( 7 , 0 ) );
```

To get the current date, specify a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)). The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Ask the map for the alarm time for today’s day-of-week.

```
LocalTime alarmTimeToday = dowToTimeMap.get( today.getDayOfWeek() );
```

You may find the [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), and [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) classes useful for determining elapsed time until next alarm.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 );
LocalTime alarmTimeTomorrow = dowToTimeMap.get( tomorrow.getDayOfWeek() );
ZonedDateTime nextAlarmZdt = ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , alarmTimeTomorrow , z );
Instant now = Instant.now();
Duration duration = Duration.between( now , nextAlarmZdt.toInstant() );
```

Check to see if the duration is negative, meaning going backwards in time. That would mean the next alarm time was either before now, or so close as to expire by the time this code ran.

```
if( duration.isNegative() ) {
    // Oops, the next alarm was within a second or so of current time, a shorter time than it took to execute this code.
    …  // Handle the problem.
}
```

You could also verify today and tomorrow, as that could shift if this code executes at the moment of midnight.

You can then interrogate the `Duration` for a number of whole seconds or milliseconds or nanoseconds, whatever you need for your alarm setting.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current day and month like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

and the day of the week (like Monday, Tuesday ... ) with

```
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK